# How to change date format of datepicker value in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker, date-formatting

I gone to many of the questions already asked in stackoverflow related to my problem, but i still i can't find any solution. I am trying to get the value from datpicker in my javascript function, but not able to change its format. By default its showing in mm/dd/yy format and i want in yyyy-mm-dd format. Can anyone please help.

Below is my html code :

```
    <html xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>
    <script>
        function getdate()
        {
         alert("Entered function");
      var date = $('#fromdate').val();
          $.datepicker.formatDate( 'yy-mm-dd' ,date );
            alert(date); }
        </script>
     </h:head>
    <body>
      <input type="text" id="fromdate" class="form-control dpd1" name="from"placeholder="Select From Date"></input>
      <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>
      <input type="text" id="todate" class="form-control dpd2" name="to" placeholder="Select To Date" ></input>
      <input type="button" onclick="getdate()" value="Change Date"></input>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();` Try this

Comment: Its still showing the same problem. Actually the format it takes from the datepicker, same its showing through the script. Its not changing or formatting.

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle of this issue

Comment: I am trying to create jsfiddle but datepicker is not getting appended to the textbox, wait will post the link soon.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/j7JMD/

Comment: Thanks a lot Sreekesh. Was looking for such, but now I am new to such designing part so not getting like how to get your example code into my webpage. Also I tried to create my jsfiddle same as yours but it was not showing datepicker. Why so ? Can you help me in learning such. Like is there any document you have then please provide me the link. Thanks again will try to use your code in my page.

Comment: Included comments in the answer posted

Answer (score 3):

```
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

    });

    function getdate()
    {
     alert("Entered function");
     var date = $('#fromdate').val();
     alert(date);
     }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The format of dates can be a combination of any of the following characters:

```
d – day of month (single digit where applicable)
dd – day of month (two digits)
m – month of year (single digit where applicable)
mm – month of year (two digits)
y – year (two digits)
yy – year (four digits)
D – short day name
DD – full day name
M – short month name
MM – long month name
'...' – any literal text string
@ - UNIX timestamp (milliseconds since 01/01/1970)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getdate()
{
    alert("Entered function");
    var date = $('#fromdate').val();
    date = $.datepicker.formatDate( 'yy-mm-dd', date );
    alert(date);
}
```

You need to assign the result of the formatDate call to your date object. Then you can alert it.

Comment: alert(date) is only not working. I think i have made any mistake in my code. Have to look for it again.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="fromdate" class="datepicker form-control dpd1" name="from" placeholder="Select From Date"></input> <span class="input-group-addon">To</span>

<input type="text" id="todate" class="datepicker form-control dpd2" name="to" placeholder="Select To Date"></input>
<input type="button" class="getdate" value="Change Date"></input>
```

JavaScript

```
//Define fields with class name 'datepicker' as jQueryUI datepicker
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' //Setting dateformat for the datepicker
});

//Binding 'onclick' function for the button with class name 'getdate'
$('.getdate').on('click', function () {
    var date = $('#fromdate').val();
    alert(date);
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7JMD/)

Answer (score 0):

Its works for me

```
<input type="text" id="fromdate" class="form-control dpd1"    name="from"placeholder="Select From Date"></input>

$('#fromdate').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
});
```